# No video signal when trying to install Windows XP

Tags: windows, video, installation

This happened to me on more than one PC. When reinstalling Windows it first loads up the BIOS and then goes past the basic installer prompt asking you to hit any key.

After that you would expect a basic blue installer, yet it's blank. Sometimes, after waiting for a long time, the video comes back on while in the middle of the installation process.

However, some machines never have video, even though the OS gets installed.

Comment: Are you using a CD provided by the laptop manufacturer? If you're just using a regular OEM CD to install Windows, it's possible that Windows just doesn't have the drivers for the video (particularly if it's an older video chipset) Please advise what source of windows you're using.

Comment: Nope oem installer and slipstreamed sp3

Comment: As noted before this is scoured with an old lifebook with a sp3  from microsofts eopen site. As well as a custom one via nlite. I found the chipset for this driver just can not find a download that is the actual driver. I have slipstreamed video not in windows xp and have this working on 2 other laptops previously not working. Invalid SATA configs usually end up in blue screens not video. Its the case in this instance you can actually install an operating system if you know the menus or throw a valid card to get video on.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed quite a few XP machines without never encountering this problem.
But all my boot CDs were downloaded directly from Microsoft, nothing ever slip-streamed myself.

I believe it's a problem with your boot CD. I suggest to recreate it, and if this happens again then review your slip-stream method.

Answer (score 0):

such issues are usually related to Windows XP's lack of native SATA support.

solutions:

slipstream an up-to-date controller driver bundle into the installation CD

change SATA/RAID settings to IDE in the BIOS

Comment: Happens on an IDE notebook :-/